# Display due amount to the user at selected bills

Tags: sql-server

Actually I am creating a receipt form in my project and the date wise bill selection is now I am cleared, but now I have one more doubt. If I select a user1 bills at 1/6/17 - 15/6/17 in the range and the sum of the amount will be shown as 10,000 rupees. Now user1 paid 5000 now how to I show balance amount at user1 when his second payment.

[ Note: User1 has already purchased at 1/6/17 - 30/6/17.  ]

```
select 
    sum(TotalValue)  bal 
from(
    select 
        ISNULL(sum(s.NetAmount),0) TotalValue 
    from Sales as s 
    where s.ConsumerID=56 
    and s.SaleDate='2017/06/10' 
    and s.SaleDate='2017/06/30' 

    union all

   select - ISNULL(sum(s.Amount),0) TotalValue 
   from Receipt  as s 
   where s.ConsumerID=56
) n
```

My query is not given the exact output.

How to I re-write in this code to get my output.

Thanks in advance..,

In my Sales table record  the sum of the column(netamount)value is 36000 between 01/06/2017 to 30/06/2017 .

Now I am entry the first receipt. So I first checking my user bill amount, To write this nested query, When my user take a choice to pays the amount for first 10 days at 3 dues.

For example 1/6/17 - 10/6/17 total amount is 15000. In first receipt user paid 5000.

In second entry I getting value of amount is 10000 but query returns 31000

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I had to start by formatting that query so we can read it. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. In your first query you have two predicates with s.SaleDate. As posted the first one it totally pointless because it will only return rows for 2017/06/30. If you want some help we need some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Why the nested query?

Comment: Can you show us what you're getting, and what you would expect to get?

Comment: @Eli why did you cram the equals signs back together like that? It makes it so much harder to read.

Comment: @SeanLange I didn't cram them back together... I just edited the original post to create line breaks, and I posted it a few seconds after yours... SO simply decided to overwrite yours with mine instead of merging them. You can re-edit it if you'd like. I didn't touch your edit, sorry if it seemed so.

Comment: Well now that you have changed the predicates to both be equal you will never get any results. There is no row that be both dates at the same time. My guess is you want s.SaleDate >= '20170610' AND s.SaleDate <= '20170630'

Comment: @Eli ahh...sorry didn't mean to sound snippy. Just struck me as odd. The editing history doesn't always make stuff like that very clear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the SQL below

```
     ;WITH cte_sales 
     AS (SELECT s.consumerid 
                ,Isnull(Sum(s.netamount), 0) TotalSalesValue 
         FROM   sales AS s 
         WHERE  s.consumerid = 56 
                AND s.saledate >= '2017/06/10' 
                AND s.saledate <= '2017/06/30' 
         GROUP  BY s.consumerid), 
     cte_recipt 
     AS (SELECT r.consumerid 
                ,Isnull(Sum(r.amount), 0) TotalReceiptValue 
         FROM   receipt AS r 
         WHERE  r.consumerid = 56 
         GROUP  BY r.consumerid) 
SELECT a.consumerid 
       ,a.totalsalesvalue - Isnull(totalreceiptvalue, 0) balance 
FROM   cte_sales a 
       LEFT JOIN cte_recipt b 
              ON a.consumerid = b.consumerid 
GROUP  BY a.consumerid
```

Another solution is

```
SELECT s.consumerid ,Isnull(Sum(s.netamount), 0)  -  Isnull(Sum(r.amount), 0) as balance
 FROM   sales AS s 
 left join  receipt AS r 
 on s.consumerid = r.consumerid

         WHERE  s.consumerid = 56 
                AND s.saledate >= '2017/06/10' 
                AND s.saledate <= '2017/06/30'
```

You need to decide which one has a better SQL Execution Plan

Comment: please explain me. why u write the with command in your query.

Comment: I used cte tables (with) for two reasons; first, I do not want to break your work line; second, do not know your modeling, index configuration, and size of tables. But you can use this query, is simple  SELECT s.consumerid, 
       Isnull(Sum(s.netamount), 0) - Isnull(Sum(r.amount), 0) AS balance 
FROM   sales AS s 
       LEFT JOIN receipt AS r 
              ON s.consumerid = r.consumerid 
WHERE  s.consumerid = 56 
       AND s.saledate >= '2017/06/10' 
       AND s.saledate <= '2017/06/30'